# Error in request with the auth module - Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

I want to add the auth module in my application but when he's trying to access to the database, he doesn't use the right fields. This is the error page that I get with the request :

> Database_Exception [ 1054 ]: Unknown column 'username' in 'where
>   clause' [ SELECT `user`.`id` AS `id`, `user`.`mail` AS `mail`,
>   `user`.`login` AS `login`, `user`.`password` AS `password`,
>   `user`.`nom` AS `nom`, `user`.`prenom` AS `prenom`, `user`.`telephone`
>   AS `telephone`, `user`.`inscription` AS `inscription`, `user`.`active`
>   AS `active`, `user`.`admin` AS `admin`, `user`.`rattachement` AS
>   `rattachement`, `user`.`organisme` AS `organisme` FROM `utilisateur`
>   AS `user` WHERE `username` = 'l.rousseaux' LIMIT 1 ]

So in the where clause, he uses `username` and in my database, I use `login`. So my question is, where can I change this parameter for him to check the right field ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: In Your ORM module Auth ORM has unique_key field for that.

Comment: you can find it OEM-> Model -> User line 129

Comment: did you managed to find solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the unique value field in Modules -> ORM -> Model -> user line 129

```
/**
* Allows a model use both email and username as unique identifiers for  login
*
* @param   string  unique value
* @return  string  field name
*/
public function unique_key($value)
{
   return Valid::email($value) ? 'email' : 'username';
}
```